# Python. Чтение из переменной построчно, аналог readline есть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, readline

В программе написана большая функция, которая **построчно** считывает данные из текстового файла и обрабатывает их по своим алгоритмам.

```
with open(FilePath, "r") as file:
    my_var1 = 'NotEnd'
    while my_var1 != ''
        my_var1 = file.readline().rstrip()
        # дальше алгоритм обработки my_var1
    print ('Ok')
```

Возникла необходимость продублировать ту же функцию, но с обработкой данных не из ***файла***, а из **переменной**. Особенность **readline**, считывает строку в файле и запоминает позицию. Новое считывание **readline** будет происходить с новой строки. Возможно ли аналогичным образом обработать переменную, содержащую многострочный текст?
Без применения `splitlines()` и списка?
Предположительный пример того, что хочется получить в результате:

```
STR_VAR = 'Многострочная\nпеременная\nстроки из которой\nбудут обрабатываться\n'
my_var1 = 'NotEnd'
while my_var1 != ''
    my_var1 = STR_VAR.readline().rstrip()
    # дальше алгоритм обработки my_var1
print ('Ok')
```

Comment: Запомнили начало. Ищете далее признак конца строки. Как нашли - выдали строку от начала до найденного конца. Какие тут сложности?

Comment: Удобнее использовать цикл for для итерации по файловым объектам: `for my_var1 in file: my_var1 = my_var1.strip() # дальше идет алгоритм обработки`. Аналогично будет работать и со `StringIO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) больше всего похоже на то, что вам нужно

```py
import io

STR_VAR = 'Многострочная\nпеременная\nстроки из которой\nбудут обрабатываться\n'

with io.StringIO(STR_VAR) as file:
    my_var1 = 'NotEnd'
    while my_var1 != '':
        my_var1 = file.readline().rstrip()
        # дальше алгоритм обработки my_var1
    print ('Ok')
```

А что касается самого цикла обработки, вот чуть более традиционный способ его организовать

```py
for my_var1 in map(str.rstrip, file):
    # дальше алгоритм обработки my_var1

print('Ok')
```

Comment: io.StringIO - это хорошо, но что делать, если в память помещается только одна строка STR_VAR (большая она)

Comment: @Виктор нет смысла специально придумывать какие-то левые ограничения, про которые автор вопроса не пишет. `StringIO` задачу решает, про ограничения по памяти в вопросе ничего нет. Если есть ограничения по памяти, тогда вообще не нужно эту строку в памяти хранить.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно. Всё протестировал. Включая заполнение стеков и нагрузку на оперативку. Полностью решает мою задачу. Не знал, что можно организовать подобную эмуляцию. Еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Делайте так:

```
import re
STR_VAR = 'Многострочная\nпеременная\nстроки из которой\nбудут обрабатываться\n'

def find_iter(s: str):
    for m in re.finditer('(.+)(?:\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r)*',s):
        yield m.group(0)

for s in find_iter(STR_VAR):
    my_var1 = s.rstrip()
    # дальше алгоритм обработки my_var1
    print(my_var1)
```

Вывод:

```
Многострочная
переменная
строки из которой
будут обрабатываться
```

PS:
зачем Вам в первом примере

```
my_var1 = 'NotEnd'
while my_var1 != '': ?
```

используйте конструкцию:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Автор как раз хотел избежать использования splitlines. Не уверен, зачем ему это нужно - может, и строка, и результирующий список в память не лезут...